# Can you know when Power Button is pressed?

Tags: ios, background, ios8, action

I would like to know if I can make an app running on background that detects when power button is pressed and runs a app action that can ignore power button actions. Thanks

Comment: Do you hate your users?

Comment: I actually love them

Comment: If I press the power button and it doesn't do what the power button does, my first instinct is to track down the person responsible and set them on fire.

Comment: Only prevent power button to shutdown and you can still shut it down if you, for example, put the correct pin

Comment: Sounds like your objective is already served by whatever iOS has for public-use terminals.  Tho preventing people from turning off public terminals is something of low consequence, generally.

Answer (score 1):

A stock (i.e. not jailbroken) iOS device's apps cannot interrupt the power button.

You can do some actions when the app is exited using `applicationDidEnterBackground`. If you need to prevent users from exiting an application for something like a kiosk, you can turn on [Guided Access mode](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612).

Comment: So not possible unless jailbroken? This is for security reasons only, and would prevent stolen iPhones from shutting down and then they could be found. But thanks for your answer, appreciate it!

Comment: @PedroGomes No, not possible. You may wish to use it for security reasons, but you can imagine that such a feature could be nastily abused by a malicious app developer who slipped a time bomb into their app.

Comment: True story, i always thought of it that way but i was never a iphone user so i could be missing out some funcionalities. Thanks again

Comment: @PedroGomes The best security for lost/stolen phones is findMyIPhone - You can set the option that gets the phone to update it's last known location before it is turned off/goes flat and this also enables activation lock so the stolen phone is useless without the corresponding iCloud account password